# Powershell Compare-Object modify side indicator

Tags: powershell

I have two text files from a print server and need to get an HTML document out of the result, when I run my current code I get the HTML created but it is filled with numbers and not the correct data.

```
$Compare = Compare-Object $Reference $Difference |
  %{
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=" {$($_.InputObject) does not exist on 01"}
    if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" {$($_.InputObject) does not exist on 02"} 
 } | Convertto-HTML -As LIST | Out-String
 
 Convertto-HTML -Head $Header -Body $Compare | Out-file $Location
```

The data should look like below (Obviously this has the side indicators)

[image]

When I include the code above this is what returns.

[image]

Comment: And what would be the correct data? What are you comparing?

Comment: You really need to show what you are using, as input, vs forcing folks to create to emulte your use case. The reason you are getting what you are getting is that is what you told Powershell to do. Silicon-based life forms, through cool and helpful and all, are stupid/well, let's say compliant. They will only do what they are told (programmed to do). So, well, you know... You are not telling PS to do what you imagine. It cannot guess at it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment.

Is this the sort of thing you are trying to do?

```
Clear-Host
$Header = @'
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
'@

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject 'D:\Temp\Source\FileList1.txt' -DifferenceObject 'D:\Temp\Source\FileList2.txt' | 
ForEach-Object {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        SideIndicator = switch ($PSItem.SideIndicator)
                        {
                            '=>' {"$($PSItem) does not exist on FileList2"}
                            '<=' {"$($PSItem) does not exist on FileList1"}
                        }
    }
} | 
ConvertTo-Html -Property '*' -Head $Header | 
Out-File -FilePath 'D:\Temp\FileCompareReport.html'

Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\FileCompareReport.html'
# Results
<#
Get-Content -Path 'D:\Temp\FileCompareReport.html'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TD {border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
</style>
</head><body>
<table>
<colgroup><col/></colgroup>
<tr><th>*</th></tr>
<tr><td>=&gt; does not exist on FileList2</td></tr>
<tr><td>&lt;= does not exist on FileList1</td></tr>
</table>
</body></html>
#>

Invoke-Item -Path 'D:\Temp\FileCompareReport.html'
```